# why is react-player playing video even when playing={false}?

Tags: reactjs, class, antd, react-player

The react-player is playing video even when [playing={false}](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player). I'm using antd modal which is wrapped around my player.
when I close the modal state changes to false. Which is passed in react-player but the player keeps on playing in the background.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Modal } from "antd";
    import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

    export class demo extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            isModalOpen: false,
            };
        }

        ConfirmationModalhandleCancel = () => {
            this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
        };
        
        ConfirmationModalPlay = () => {
            this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
        };

        getVideo = () => {
            console.log("Modal state",this.state.isModalOpen)
            return (
            <ReactPlayer
                playing={this.state.isModalOpen}
                className="introductionVideoLearningPlanPage"
                controls={true}
                url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agi4geKb8v8"
            />
            );
        };
        
        getIntroVideoModal = () => {
            return (
            <Modal
            title={null}
            footer={null}
            visible={this.state.isModalOpen}
            onCancel={this.ConfirmationModalhandleCancel}
            width="fit-content"
            bodyStyle={{ padding: '0' }}
        >
            {this.getVideo()}
        </Modal>
            )
        }
        
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.getIntroVideoModal()}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default demo
```

I have observed that the console.log("Modal state", this.state.isModalOpen) is consoling false when the modal closes but the player keeps on playing. react-player version: 2.6.2 and 2.9.0.
How do I stop playing the video once the modal closes?

Comment: your logic is wrong when you open model that time `isModalOpen` is true

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya Yeah! That's how it's supposed to be when modal opens `isModalOpen` becomes true and when modal closes it becomes false. I have also tried `playing={!this.state.isModalOpen}` but same thing happens.

Comment: try with hard coded false it's working ?

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya not exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is specific to `antd modal`. I tried reactstrap modal and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Friend, you can go with **Antd Modal** itself, nothing wrong with that. To be able to stop the video playback when the Modal gets closed, you must pass the property

```
// add this property to your ant Modal    
destroyOnClose={true}
```

to the Modal. This is an another workaround with which I achieved the expected behavior. Thanks

Comment: highlight the code rather then wrap it in quotes